# Can someone provide a simple Python example for Twitter status updates?

Tags: python, twitter, oauth

I'm having problems to find a simple python twitter oauth example which shows how to post a user status on Twitter. Could you help me?

Answer (score 5):

Check out Mike Knapp's library on [GitHub](https://github.com/mikeknapp/AppEngine-OAuth-Library).
Nice and simple, no install needed.

Answer (score 4):

Here's [an example](https://github.com/litl/rauth/blob/master/examples/twitter-timeline-cli.py) that will get you authed with Twitter using [rauth](https://github.com/litl/rauth).

After that point all you'd have to do to update the authenticated user's status is:

```
r = session.post('statuses/update.json',
                 data={'status': 'Updating my status from the cmd line.'})
print r.json()
```

(You only need to care about the code up until you retrieve your authenticated session object, i.e. [line 20](https://github.com/litl/rauth/blob/master/examples/twitter-timeline-cli.py#L20).)

Hope this helps!

**Edit**

You will need to get your own consumer_key and consumer_secret for this to work because the rauth demo app does not have write permissions, for obvious reasons. So you'll end up with this response if you try to run the modified script without updating the credentials:

```
{u'request': u'/1/statuses/update.json', u'error': u'Read-only application cannot POST'}
```

Ensure your application is allowed to write and it should work as expected.

Comment: after you've authenticated, how do you save the session object, so you don't have to authenticate each time (i.e. when running a REST call from the console app?)? Is it possible to simply create the session object from the consumer key/secret and the access key/secret? What if I already have those 4 pieces of information, how do I create the session object, so I don't need to do this OAuth dance? Thanks!

Comment: @vgoklani here's a detailed answer to your questions: https://github.com/litl/rauth/issues/83#issuecomment-15629796. In short, yes you can create a session object directly or you can use the service wrapper to emit a new session with a given access token.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look on tweepy: http://code.google.com/p/tweepy/

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out http://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2 ?

Comment: There's no example of what the op requested there.

Answer (score 0):

Matthew A. Russell has written an excellent book on this, Mining the social web. Take a look at his excample source for OAuth to twitter. The code is available here, and i recommend his book also, covering not only twitter, but facebook and linkedin aswell.

The code is found here: [OAuth to twitter and collect friends id's](https://github.com/ptwobrussell/Mining-the-Social-Web/blob/master/python_code/friends_followers__get_friends.py)

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://milindshakya.tumblr.com/post/4188710184/twitter-connect-in-django-using-oauth) is a simple twitter oauth example I wrote as a blog sometime ago. Hope this helps.

Comment: "Once you have the user’s access token, tweeting on behalf of the user is super simple.".  That's basically the only thing relevant to the original question, this isn't really relevat.

Comment: Hugo, Thanks for the input. But there is an example on how to post status updates to twitter, exactly above the statement you quoted from this blog [post](http://milindshakya.tumblr.com/post/4188710184/twitter-connect-in-django-using-oauth).

Answer (score 0):

If you're refering to http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/ ..

On that page it is documented as

> > > > api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='consumer_key', consumer_secret='consumer_secret', access_token_key='access_token',
> > > >         access_token_secret='access_token_secret')
>
> To see if your credentials
>   are successful:
>
> > > > print api.VerifyCredentials() {"id": 16133, "location": "Philadelphia", "name": "bear"}

That works. Ofcourse, your consumer key *should* never be human-readable in your application. But it would work even if it was.

*-pike

Answer (score 0):

I've written an [extremely simple twitter client](https://github.com/hobarrera/nanotwit/blob/master/src/opt/nanotwit/nanotwit.py) (which is just for tweeting).
The source isn't the cleanest around, but the entire thing (including UI) is under 200 lines, so you should be able to extract anything you need from it: